# Yapf wanting a linebreak and tabbing when it shouldn't

Tags: python, yapf

I'm having an issue with yapf behaving differently on my local machine and on a jenkins pipeline build.

This is my line:

```
groups = thing.func(
    *[iter(people)] * constants.MAX_PEOPLE_PER_CREATE)
```

That yapf keeps telling me is wrong (and failing, causing the whole build to fail), telling me the correct way is:

```
groups = thing.func(*[iter(people)] * 
                    constants.MAX_PEOPLE_PER_CREATE)
```

I'm assuming it's some kind of version mismatch on docker, but I can't figure out where it might be. I've confirmed all my python libraries are the same. Even if I force it to look like what it wants, it throws another fit with an error that you can't have a line break after an operator.